# Can I query a BQ table as it is being overwritten?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following use case:
- 1 BigQuery table needs to be overwritten every hour. 
- Overwritting the table can take up to a couple of minutes since it's quite large (>1m rows)
- This table is queried via an API call.

If an API call occurs while the table is being overwritten, what happens? 
What is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery provides the property of snapshot isolation, and if you initiate the query at time t1, the overwrite completes at t2, and the query completes at t3, the query will see the table as it was before the overwrite.

Comment: Sweet, thanks! I can't seem to find documentation on this. Can you provide a link?

Comment: I thought I knew where it says something along these lines but I'm having trouble finding it now :( I'm a first-party source, in any case.

Comment: ok thanks. What does first-party source mean? (as in you're the first to respond?)

Comment: It means that I'm an engineer on the BigQuery team.

Comment: I think I found the doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/bigquery-data-warehouse):Backup and recovery
BigQuery addresses backup and disaster recovery at the service level. Also, by maintaining a complete 7-day history of changes against your tables, BigQuery allows you to query a point-in-time snapshot of your data by using either table decorators or SYSTEM_TIME AS OF in the FROM clause. You can easily revert changes without having to request a recovery from backups. (When a table is explicitly deleted, its history is flushed after 2 days.)

Comment: What will happen if overwrite initiates at time t1, query completes at t2, overwrite finishes at t3. Will the query only read partial data ?

Comment: @GodBlessYou you should probably post a new question. I am no longer with the BigQuery team.